# Cannot execute query in GraphQL

Tags: spring, graphql

I'm trying to get into GraphQL and I followed a tutorial for a simple GraphQL + Spring + MySQL application, and I remade it for my own database. But when I try to execute my *findAllDocuments* query, I get this response in Postman:

```
    "data": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'findAllDocuments' in type 'query' is undefined @ 'findAllDocuments'",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 5,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "description": "Field 'findAllDocuments' in type 'query' is undefined",
            "validationErrorType": "FieldUndefined",
            "queryPath": [
                "findAllDocuments"
            ],
            "errorType": "ValidationError",
            "path": null,
            "extensions": null
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the entity I'm trying to get (it has some complex datatypes like Group or Media, that have similar implementation as *Document* class, I didn't include them to save space):

```
@Table(name = "documents")
public class Document {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "doc_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;

    @Column(name = "data_asc")
    private String dataAsc;

    @Column(name = "external_link")
    private String externalLink;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "doc_id")
    private List<DocumentForum> forums;

    @Column(name = "navbar")
    private String navbar;

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "publish_start")
    private Date publishStart;

    @Column(name = "publish_end")
    private Date publishEnd;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserDetails author;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document")
    private List<Media> media;

    @Column(name = "temp_id")
    private Integer tempId;

    @Column(name = "views_total")
    private int viewsTotal;

    @Column(name = "views_month")
    private int viewsMonth;

    @Column(name = "searchable")
    private boolean searchable;

    @Column(name = "available")
    private boolean available;

    @Column(name = "cacheable")
    private boolean cacheable;

    @Column(name = "file_name")
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "file_change")
    private Date fileChange;

    @Column(name = "sort_priority")
    private int sortPriority;

    @Column(name = "header_doc_id")
    private int headerDocId;

    @Column(name = "menu_doc_id")
    private int menuDocId;

    @Column(name = "footer_doc_id")
    private int footerDocId;

    @Column(name = "password_protected")
    private String passwordProtected;

    @Column(name = "html_head")
    private String htmlHead;

    @Column(name = "perex_place")
    private String perexPlace;

    @Column(name = "perex_image")
    private String perexImage;

    @Column(name = "perex_group")
    private String perexGroup;

    @Column(name = "show_in_menu")
    private boolean showInMenu;

    @Column(name = "event_date")
    private Date eventDate;

    @Column(name = "virtual_path")
    private String virtualPath;

    @Column(name = "sync_id")
    private int syncId;

    @Column(name = "sync_status")
    private int syncStatus;

    @Column(name = "logon_page_doc_id")
    private int logonPageDocId;

    @Column(name = "right_menu_doc_id")
    private int rightMenuDocId;

    @Column(name = "field_a")
    private String fieldA;

    @Column(name = "field_b")
    private String fieldB;

    @Column(name = "field_c")
    private String fieldC;

    @Column(name = "field_d")
    private String fieldD;

    @Column(name = "field_e")
    private String fieldE;

    @Column(name = "field_f")
    private String fieldF;

    @Column(name = "field_g")
    private String fieldG;

    @Column(name = "field_h")
    private String fieldH;

    @Column(name = "field_i")
    private String fieldI;

    @Column(name = "field_j")
    private String fieldJ;

    @Column(name = "field_k")
    private String fieldK;

    @Column(name = "field_l")
    private String fieldL;

    @Column(name = "disable_after_end")
    private boolean disableAfterEnd;

    @Column(name = "forum_count")
    private int forumCount;

    @Column(name = "field_m")
    private String fieldM;

    @Column(name = "field_n")
    private String fieldN;

    @Column(name = "field_o")
    private String fieldO;

    @Column(name = "field_p")
    private String fieldP;

    @Column(name = "field_q")
    private String fieldQ;

    @Column(name = "field_r")
    private String fieldR;

    @Column(name = "field_s")
    private String fieldS;

    @Column(name = "field_t")
    private String fieldT;

    @Column(name = "require_ssl")
    private boolean requireSsl;

    @Column(name = "root_group_l1")
    private Integer rootGroupL1;

    @Column(name = "root_group_l2")
    private Integer rootGroupL2;

    @Column(name = "root_group_l3")
    private Integer rootGroupL3;

*********SETTER AND GETTERS*********
```

This is the .graphqls file for *Document* class:

```
scalar Date

type Document{
    id: Int!
    title: String!
    data: String!
    dataAsc: String!
    externalLink: String!
    forums: [DocumentForum]!
    navbar: String!
    dateCreated: Date!
    publishStart: Date
    publishEnd: Date
    author: UserDetails!
    group: Group!
    media: [Media]!
    tempId: Int!
    viewsTotal: Int!
    viewsMonth: Int!
    searchable: Boolean!
    available: Boolean!
    cacheable: Boolean!
    fileName: String
    fileChange: Date
    sortPriority: Int!
    headerDocId: Int!
    menuDocId: Int!
    footerDocId: Int!
    passwordProtected: String
    htmlHead: String!
    perexPlace: String!
    perexImage: String!
    perexGroup: String
    showInMenu: Boolean!
    eventDate: Date
    virtualPath: String!
    syncId: Int!
    syncStatus: Int!
    logonPageDocId: Int!
    rightMenuDocId: Int!
    fieldA: String!
    fieldB: String!
    fieldC: String!
    fieldD: String!
    fieldE: String!
    fieldF: String!
    fieldG: String!
    fieldH: String!
    fieldI: String!
    fieldJ: String!
    fieldK: String!
    fieldL: String!
    disableAfterEnd: Boolean!
    forumCount: Int!
    fieldM: String!
    fieldN: String!
    fieldO: String!
    fieldP: String!
    fieldQ: String!
    fieldR: String!
    fieldS: String!
    fieldT: String!
    requireSsl: Boolean!
    rootGroupL1: Int
    rootGroupL2: Int
    rootGroupL3: Int
}

type Query {
    findAllDocuments: [Document]!
}
```

This is the *Query* resolver class:

```
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    private final DocumentRepository documentRepository;
    private final DocumentForumRepository documentForumRepository;
    private final GroupRepository groupRepository;
    private final MediaRepository mediaRepository;
    private final UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;

    @Autowired
    public Query(DocumentRepository documentRepository,
                 DocumentForumRepository documentForumRepository,
                 GroupRepository groupRepository,
                 MediaRepository mediaRepository,
                 UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository){

        this.documentRepository = documentRepository;
        this.documentForumRepository = documentForumRepository;
        this.groupRepository = groupRepository;
        this.mediaRepository = mediaRepository;
        this.userDetailsRepository = userDetailsRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Document> findAllDocuments(){
        return documentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Iterable<DocumentForum> findAllDocumentForums(){
        return documentForumRepository.findAll();
    }
    public Iterable<Group> findAllGroups(){
        return groupRepository.findAll();
    }
    public Iterable<Media> findAllMedia(){
        return mediaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And this is the *DocumentResolver* class:

```
public class DocumentResolver implements GraphQLResolver<Document> {
    private DocumentForumRepository documentForumRepository;
    private GroupRepository groupRepository;
    private MediaRepository mediaRepository;
    private UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DocumentResolver(DocumentForumRepository documentForumRepository,
            GroupRepository groupRepository,
            MediaRepository mediaRepository,
            UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository){

        this.documentForumRepository = documentForumRepository;
        this.groupRepository = groupRepository;
        this.mediaRepository = mediaRepository;
        this.userDetailsRepository = userDetailsRepository;
    }

    public List<DocumentForum> getForums(Document document){
        return documentForumRepository.findAllById(document.getId());
    }

    public UserDetails getAuthor(Document document) throws ObjectNotFoundException {
        Optional<UserDetails> optionalUserDetails = userDetailsRepository.findById(document.getId());
        if(optionalUserDetails.isPresent()){
            return optionalUserDetails.get();
        }else{
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    public Group getGroup(Document document) throws ObjectNotFoundException {
        Optional<Group> optionalGroup = groupRepository.findById(document.getId());
        if(optionalGroup.isPresent()){
            return optionalGroup.get();
        }else{
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    public List<Media> getMedia(Document document) {
        return mediaRepository.findAllById(document.getId());
    }
}
```

The query I try to send from Postman:

```
{
    findAllDocuments{
        id
        title
        data
    }
}
```

Everything works in my smaller project and I can't pinpoint what's the problem here. If anything else is needed, please let me know and I'll provide it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using graphql-java-tools?

Comment: Why do you have two query resolvers implementing GraphQLResolver<Document> and GraphQLResolver? And also why findAllDocuments is not inside the implementation of  GraphQLResolver<Document> but the other one? Maybe that's why it can't resolve the query.

Comment: I am using graphql-java-tools. **Query** resolver is implementing **GraphQLQueryResolver** and is used for all queries. **DocumentResolver** is implementing **GraphQLResolver<Document>** and is used for getting all complex datatypes in my **Document** class (for example _UserDetails_).